# Function is not defined, failed to load sources jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            function slideSwitch() {
                var $active = $('#slideShow IMG.active');

                if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideShow IMG:last');

                var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                    : $('#slideShow IMG:first');

                $active.addClass('last-active');

                $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                    .addClass('active')
                    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                    });
            }


                setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );

        });
```

And it errors with slideSwitch() is not defined?? any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a string with `setInterval` it will be evaludated in the scope of the `window` object, and as you declared the function locally in another function, it's not available globally.

Just use the function name instead of a string with code that calls the function:

```
window.setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
```

This will pass a reference to the function instead of a string, so it doesn't rely on the name of the function when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your function outside the ready event.  I don't think there's anything wrong syntactically, though might be that it can't find the function in that scope.